# Restrict client from html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I serve a HTML page, which presents within my users-authentication system.

The HTML page should be unreachable when non-authenticated client tries to access it.

So, I have the following JS code:

```
let isAuthenticated = false;
let username;

(async () => {
    // Retrieve username if logged-in
    try {
        const serverResponse = await fetch('api/auth/getUsername', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token') || ''}`,
            },
        });
        const serverResponseData = await serverResponse.json();

        if (serverResponseData.success) {
            isAuthenticated = true;
            username = serverResponseData.data.username;
        } else {
            return window.location.href = '/';
        }
    } catch { } finally {
        $(document).ready(() => {
            // Username and auth buttons elements
            const $authButtonsContainerELM = $('#authButtonsContainer');
            const $navUserContainerELM = $('#navUserContainer');
            const $usernameText = $('#usernameText');

            if (isAuthenticated) {
                $authButtonsContainerELM.css('display', 'none');
                $navUserContainerELM.css('display', 'flex');
                $usernameText.html(username);
            } else {
                $authButtonsContainerELM.css('display', 'flex');
                $navUserContainerELM.css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>post blog</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery.min.js">\x3C/script>');</script>

    <script src="./JS/index.js"></script>

    <div>blbalalal</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that the actual HTML code in my source is a bit more complex of-course.

So basically when I go as not authenticated in my browser, I try to access this page.
What happens is, I can see the HTML page for 1 sec then I got redirect back to `/` path. But I do see the HTML. How can I execute my JS code before the HTML loads?

Comment: '*The HTML page should be unreachable when non-authenticated client tries to access it.*' in this case JS is the last thing you should be using. It is trivial to work around by simply turning it off in the browser settings. If you require this level of security, do it server side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is only practice. Security is off topic for this thread.

Comment: You can not run JavaScript before the HTML.
browser first opens the HTML file and then runs or load any JS that is found.
So if you only rely on client side redirect that is controlled by JS, you will always get the HTML first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the `auth_token` in a cookie... Instead of `localStorage`. So the cookie would be sent along the HTTP request... And the decision to serve the protected content would be made server-side.

But if you insist... Just to *practice*... You could hide the HTML by default via CSS for that split second:

Add the `hiddenOnLoad` class to the HTML markup:

```
<body class="hiddenOnLoad">
```

Which would just hide everything:

```
body.hiddenOnLoad *{
  display: none !important;
}
```

And inside `$(document).ready()`... It the authentication succeeded:

```
if(isAuthenticated){
  $("body").removeClass("hiddenOnLoad")
}
```